# watermark on off in jquery

Tags: jquery, watermark

I have added a watermark text in an image when a check box is checked, but now I want to remove the watermark text when the checkbox is not checked.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="watermark" value="yes" id="water_mark"> 

    $("#water_mark").click(function(e){
            if(document.getElementById('water_mark').checked) {
                 $('img').watermark({
                    text: 'I am success',
                    textWidth: 200
                 });
            } else {        
            //
            }
    });
```

Please help me!

Comment: I have use watermark.min.js file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing the library does is add text with CSS styles https://github.com/sagivo/jQuery-Watermark/blob/master/jquery-watermark.js

Guess you could just remove it like this:

```
$('img').val('').css({'color':'none'});
```

Comment: maybe **"transparent"** rather than **"none"**

Comment: What's the length of $('img') when you put it in the console? If you don't have a length of 1, it's an issue with the selector. I'd recommend naming your image so you can reference the element directly: $('#SomeID') And let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same image without watermark in the else case or you can use unchecked trigger also.

```
 $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
            console.log("CCCCheckeddddddd");

       } 
        else
            {
                 $('img')
                console.log("UNCheckeddddddd");
}    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set that watermark text to empty string may be it can help you.

```
$("#water_mark").click(function(e){
        if(document.getElementById('water_mark').checked) {
             $('img').watermark({
                text: 'I am success',
                textWidth: 200
             });
        } else {        
        $('img').watermark({
                text: '',
                textWidth: 0
             });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found for this...

when check box first time check before get old image src that mean without watermark image

```
var counter = 1;
        $("#water_mark").click(function(e){
            if(counter%2!=0){
            watermarkimg = $("img").attr("src");
            //console.log(watermarkimg);
            }

            if(document.getElementById('water_mark').checked) {

                $('img').watermark({
                    text: 'I am success',
                    textWidth: 200
                });

            } else {

                //console.log(watermarkimg);
                $('img').attr("src", watermarkimg);
            }
            counter++;
        });
```

and when second time check to checkbox image replace in without watermark  text

Hope help this! and Thanks For everyone who give me answer.

Thanks